# HTML output element not reporting value

Tags: javascript, html

The output elemement is listening to a HTML5 range slider.

It fails to report the range value:

```
 var outputElement = document.createElement('output');
  outputElement.setAttribute('for', 'myRange');
  outputElement.setAttribute('name', 'x');
  document.body.appendChild(outputElement);
```

Plnkr here: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/PlygAYJpxfzQIB5ywW2I?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input and output element need to be in a form. Then when you modify the input elements in the form you change the output element:

```
rangeCreator.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var form = document.createElement("form");
  form.id = 'form1';
  form.oninput = function () {
    x.value = myRange.value;
  }
  document.body.appendChild(form);
  var rangeInput = document.createElement('input');
  rangeInput.setAttribute('type', 'range');
  rangeInput.setAttribute('min', '0');
  rangeInput.setAttribute('max', '100');
  rangeInput.setAttribute('id', 'myRange');
  rangeInput.setAttribute('name', 'myRange');

  //rangeInput.addEventListener('input', displayValue);

  form.appendChild(rangeInput);


  var outputElement = document.createElement('output');
  outputElement.setAttribute('for', 'myRange');
  outputElement.setAttribute('name', 'x');
  outputElement.id = "x";
  form.appendChild(outputElement);
});
```

I have also updated your example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VlFBp2BMfCvCgHrePM28?p=preview).

Comment: Ideally I believe the output should autoupdate without any need for javascript. Refer: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_output

Comment: Check out the form's oninput attribute. It runs javascript. Initially I also thought it should work out of the box, but that doesn't seem to be the case :(